libssh2-1.11.0 returns -41 error working with openssl-3.0.13 on Windows
I got the error code -41 while connecting to the SFTP server on Windows.
Did some debuggings in libssh2, this is caused by the failure of decrypt data in _libssh2_cipher_crypt(), the root cause is the address of "algo" was changed at runtime.
In the struct "libssh2_crypt_method_aes256_gcm", the member "algo" is set to "EVP_aes_256_gcm", so the address of "algo" should be same as "EVP_aes_256_gcm", but at runtime, the address of "EVP_aes_256_gcm" was changed.
static const LIBSSH2_CRYPT_METHOD libssh2_crypt_method_aes256_gcm = {
    "aes256-gcm@openssh.com",
    "",
    16,                         /* blocksize */
    12,                         /* initial value length */
    32,                         /* secret length -- 32*8 == 256bit */
    LIBSSH2_CRYPT_FLAG_INTEGRATED_MAC | LIBSSH2_CRYPT_FLAG_PKTLEN_AAD,
    &crypt_init,
    &crypt_encrypt,
    &crypt_dtor,
    EVP_aes_256_gcm
    //_libssh2_cipher_aes256gcm
};

Anyone knows why?
libssh2 linked the import libraries of openssl (libcrypto.lib and libssl.lib) and the dll files was copied int to %PATH%.
Any comments would be greatly appreciated.
